# Terminology: complex of sheaves with cohomology sheaves concentrated in degree zero

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, chain-complexes, terminology

What is the proper terminology for a complex of sheaves $\mathcal F^\bullet$ whose homology sheaves $\mathcal H^i\mathcal F^\bullet$ vanish for $i\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can call it pure object.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of [t-structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-structure#t-structures), it's not unreasonable to call this just a "sheaf".  That is, in the natural t-structure on the derived category, the core is exactly the full subcategory of these things.  In the perverse t-structure it is, by definition, the category of [perverse sheaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_sheaves).  If one can say that a complex with vanishing positive and negative perverse cohomology is a "perverse sheaf" surely one can also say that a complex satisfying the vanishing of positive and negative cohomology is just a sheaf.